# Google oAuth2 general questions

Tags: oauth-2.0

I am trying to develop a Java application that will push a file to Google Cloud and I am stuck on the oAuth2 part of it. I've created the application, have the API Key, ClientID, oauth2 Client Id, and the oauth2 client secret.

Isn't the API Key supposed to take place of having a browser popup and ask for google account credentials? To coin the phrase, can someone explain the process in heavy detail?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Please go through the Authz code flow of OpenID Connect documentation as it will be difficult and repetitive to put the same information again.
http://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#CodeFlowAuth

for further issues check stackoverflow, if already answered or put a new question